# How add name input submit() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a JavaScript that changes the attribute of the input button to "disabled", so the user don't submit the page twice.

```
// Disables multiple submit
function disableSubmit (btn, submitForm) {
    // Sets button as disabled, changes class and cursor
    $(btn).attr("disabled", true);
    $(btn).toggleClass("disabled alt2");
    $(btn).css('cursor', 'initial');
    $(btn).attr("value", "Sender...");
    // Submits form
    $(submitForm).submit();
}

// Disables submit for order form
$("#send-order").click(function () {
    return disableSubmit(this, "#order");
});
```

The problem is that I need to track the name of the button submitting the page so I can handle it in my Django `view.py` file.

## HTML

```
<input value="Send bestilling" id="foo" name="send-order" type="submit" class="button alt2">
```

## View.py

```
request.POST.get("send-order", False)
```

But if I use my script to submit the page, I can't get the name of the input submitting the page. Is there any way to set a name for the button submitting the page in my script?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
$(submitForm).submit().attr("name", "send-order");
```

## Solution

I had to change the code inside `views.py` in order to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by creating a hidden input on your form, with a name of its own. Something like below.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="buttonName" id="buttonName" />
```

Then, in your disableSubmit function, make it set the value of that input before submitting.

```js
$(submitForm)
 .find("input[name=buttonName]")
 .attr("value",
  $(btn).attr("name")
 );
```

From there, you can just retrieve the "buttonName" value in your View.py.

Comment: `$(submitForm).submit().attr("value", $(btn).attr("name");` wouldn't this have the same result?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, because what you're doing is first *submitting*, and *then* setting the value. If you want the value to be passed, you need to change it first, then submit. I.e. `$(submitForm).attr("value", $(btn).attr("name")).submit();`. The order matters. EDIT: To answer your question, it wouldn't have the same result as the code I've posted.

Comment: OK. But why wouldn't it work if instead of creating a new button I simply use the one I am using to submit?

Comment: Anyway, having a new hidden input didn't work either. I think I will have to change my logic and stop searching for that button.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you create a new button. I'm suggesting you create a hidden input. Anyway, if you just use the button you're using now, and you give it a name, the value which will be passed is the text of the button. For example, a button like this: `<input type="submit" name="test" value="Submit Me Now!" />` will pass the value "Submit Me Now!" to request.POST.get("test"). What you're asking is to use the "name" of the button, which is not the same. Also, the "value" attribute on the `<form />` element does not get passed.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that is not different from what I tried to do. My actual button already has a name, but it gets lost once the JavaScript function submits the form. I tried your suggestion and still did not work. I created a hidden button and everything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use preventdefault or return false

```
$("#send-order").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    return disableSubmit(this, "#order");
});
```

Or

```
<input id="send-order" value="Send" type="submit" onclick="disableSubmit(this, '#order');return false" />
```

Comment: I added preventdefault() and also returned false. It still did not work.